# Increase the validity period of users in Identity

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm migrating an ASP.NET website from the old membership provider to ASP.NET Identity. I use a new ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project.

How to increase the validity period of users in Identity?

This is my startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(option => option.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectDbContex>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddErrorDescriber<PersianIdentityErrorDescriber>();
```

Comment: the existing time for a logged in user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to let the signed in user to keep sign in status longer, you can update the expire time by adding this code just behind your `services.AddIdentity`.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
```